# Is it possible to override doWithApplicationContext method of Grails plugin?

Tags: grails

I use the buggy [plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/quartz), and I can't wait for the bug to be fixed.  I need to override the method in `QuartzGrailsPlugin` somehow:

```
def doWithApplicationContext = { applicationContext ->
    application.jobClasses.each { GrailsJobClass jobClass ->
        scheduleJob(jobClass, applicationContext, hasHibernate(manager))
    }
    log.debug("Scheduled Job Classes count: " + application.jobClasses.size())
}
```

Perhaps, I should prevent call of `scheduleJob` method.

Or is the only right way forking this plugin?

Comment: Has the issue been reported in JIRA?

Comment: Yes, https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPQUARTZ-144